# Can I filter out non-starter deck cards?

Tags: scrolls

In scrolls, the search function enables you to do advanced searches, whether it is about the type of energy, the card type of a specific detail (like the creature type).

Looking in the wiki, there isn't anything about sorting out (removing) cards that came from the starter decks, which have a lock that makes it unsellable and untradable.

**I was wondering, is there any way to filter out tradable cards with from the untradables?**
*I kinda accidentally wrecked all my starter decks, and forgot the contents.*

---

**Note:** The answer for finding the starter decks' contents can be found on the wiki ([Growth](http://www.scrollsguide.com/wiki/Growth_Starter), [Energy](http://www.scrollsguide.com/wiki/Energy_Starter), [Decay](http://www.scrollsguide.com/wiki/Decay_Starter) and [Order](http://www.scrollsguide.com/wiki/Order_Starter)), but that isn't what I'm asking for.